# How to perform a factory reset for Canon MF720C Series MFP?

Tags: printer

The System Manager PIN for a MF726Cdw unit was not entered correctly, and the technician cannot recall what was typed instead.  Is it possible to factory reset one of these series multi-function printers?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with these printers, bit is the following possible?

<Menu>  <System Management Settings>  <Initialize Menu>  <Initialize All>  <Yes>    Restart the machine if necessary.                

Although I would assume the PIN is required to do this, I thought it would be worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

I spent a good amount of time searching for this solution as well because I'm in the exact situation as you. I wasn't able to find anything helpful so ended up calling Canon support. To factory reset a Canon ImageClass MF726Cdw, do the following:

1. Press and hold number "4" button
2. While holding the button, turn off the printer using the power switch, do not let go of the button
3. Continue holding it while switching the power back on until it completely boots and is at the menu screen.

Hope that helps